# How to use CSS to ensure items remain offscreen even if window is resized?

Tags: jquery, css, margin, slide

I am trying to implement a type of slider using jquery. However this question is about the CSS involved in trying to achieve the functionality.

My site design occupies a central column of width 960px. Within this layout there is a central element, that I wish to slide right, on click of a "next" button, and at the same time, another element of the same class slides in from the left to occupy the space vacated. I have drawn a diagram of what I am trying to achieve.[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/692/61886077.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/692/61886077.png)

In this diagram the red blocks are the element I want to slide in and out, it is grouped by a div which moves left to produce the effect using jQuery

I have 2 main questions:

1. How do I get the correct margin values, given that the browser window width can vary and that all elements that are not the current item should be offscreen?

2.If the user were to resize the margins could be dynamically altered based on the values returned using the jQuery resize() event. Or is there a neater quicker better way of doing it using pure CSS?

Comment: You could also take a look at the CSS they are using to build a jQuery coda slider (http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/).  Seems like it's similar to the effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I saw this but this is a vertical adaptation, whereas mine is intended to move horizontally

Comment: The Coda slider is exactly what you're after. What you need is a wrapper containing the panes, that hides the overflow. Look again at the Coda slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a div in the middle, that have margin: auto so that it will always be centered.
I'm guessing your (red) boxes will always be the same size? Have this centered div with this size, and overflow: hidden. Then inside this div, create the three other divs, which will be moved inside that fixed div size and not the browser window size.

Something like:

```
<body style="text-align: center">
    <div id="container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 960px; height: 600px; margin: auto; position: relative">
     <div id="slider" style="width: 9999px; position: absolute">
      <div id="first" style="width: 960px; float left;"></div>
      <div id="second" ...></div>
      <div id="third" ...></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So you move that slider div inside the container setting left: 960px times the number of boxes

Comment: In an ideal world, the new div would enter from the left edge of the browser window, and exit through the right edge of the window. i.e. the div would occupy 100% of the window, but the red box would be 960px and centered.

Comment: To use the whole window, you could center it using the browser window size, position the red box to left: ($(window).width() / 2) - 960/2. And to move it outside the window, move it to left: -960px while having position absolute. Perhaps you can change to position: relative and margin: auto once the box is done animating. That way it would be centered horizontally even on resize

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just `display: none;` the red boxes until they were needed?

When they need to move, you could position the boxes at the edge, then slide them on:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Vsjay/